# Missing fonts in R and RMarkdown after compiling R

Tags: r, image, fonts, r-markdown, renv

I installed an older version of R (4.0.2) from source on my computer following the instruction on https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215488098-Installing-multiple-versions-of-R-on-Linux and I work with `rmarkdown` and `knitr` packages in RStudio for my analyses. I also work with `renv` package in order to have a more reproducible environment and code.

My problem is that my plots, which are inline, lack the fonts. Here is an example:

I have a table with 2 columns, PT and M and my code is a simple ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame( "A" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
"M" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
"n" = c(3, 29, 13,  7,  0,  3,  0, 22, 13,  4,  3,  1,  0,  1,  8,  3,  4,  1,  0,  0,  0))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x=A, y=M, size = n)) + 
   geom_point()
```

[image]

I really don't know where the problem comes from: missing package in Linux, problems with R, RStudio or `rmarkdown` ?

Does someone have an idea ?

### SOLUTION

I installed [Helvetica.ttf.gz](http://laplace.physics.ubc.ca/Doc/rnpletal/Helvetica.ttf.gz) on my ubuntu:

```
gunzip Helvetica.ttf.gz 
sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/truetype/myfonts
sudo mv Helvetica.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/myfonts/.
sudo fc-cache -f -v /usr/share/fonts/truetype/myfonts/
```

Comment: Are you from France?  Have a Fr locale? Can you add your code to question?

Comment: Yes I am from France and my locale is Fr_UTF8. I added my command line in the question.

Comment: Do you use Linux?

Comment: Yes, Kubuntu 20.04

Comment: I have a Windows, don't know. Whether could I help to you. Can you give to me a small reproducible example. This font is default or you want to use a custom one?

Comment: The labels are supposed to be default labels, I didn't add custom labels and didn't touch any option regarding labels. I added a simple dataframe in the main question, you can reproduce the code. But, indeed, I think that my problem comes from my locale parameters and the way I installed R but I need this version.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try some things.

Test code:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + 
     geom_bar() +
     annotate("text", x = c(1,5,7), y=10000, label = c("un", "deux", "trois")) + 
     ggtitle("Je ne parle pas le français")
```

Find "Tools -> Global Options -> Appearance" and try to change your editor font to Ubuntu Mono (it is your native OS font).
https://askubuntu.com/questions/97469/what-is-the-default-debian-ubuntu-console-tty-font-called

And say after, what do you see.

---

Look also *there*:

[R plots: Corrupted/missing characters for devices other than pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796585/r-plots-corrupted-missing-characters-for-devices-other-than-pdf)

and *there*:

[rstudio corrupted letter and number in plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107635/rstudio-corrupted-letter-and-number-in-plot)

Comment: The editor font was already to Ubuntu Mono. I still have the problem of missing fonts with this code. I have to add: I use `renv` to manage packages and try to have a more reproducible environment. I see this problem when using this rmarkdown and renv setup.

Comment: I am not sure. I added some links into the answer.